# Flutter Listview.builder with http Request refreshes unwontedly when I navigate to other pages and go back

Tags: flutter

I have this list view set up in a tab bar, when I navigate to other tabs and go back, the list view refreshes and sends a new http request to the database, how do I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'individual_page.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FriendsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FriendsPageState createState() => FriendsPageState();
}

class FriendsPageState extends State<FriendsPage> {
  Map data;
  List userData;

  Future getFriends() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
    debugPrint(response.body);

    data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      userData = data["data"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getFriends();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add_circle,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:            FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
       color: Colors.pink,
    child: Container(
      height: 30,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Social}",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
             ),
           ),
        ),
        ),
     ),
      body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userData[index].   ["avatar"]),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                child: Text(
                  "${userData[index]["first_name"]} "
                      "${userData[index]["last_name"]}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                ),
            )
             ],
          ),
            ),
         );
       },
     )),
);
```

}
}

I want the ListView to load once and then stay loaded in the background, I don't want it to reload every time I navigate pages!

Comment: it is better to use `FutureBuilder` see this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwHMSxSWIvQ&t=0s&list=PLDzUlNXy9DYvGJVIe9C2LV4jzeanidEAR&index=2 ; looks like this is what you want.
Comment if you have a problem

Comment: I tried it but the same problem still happens. When I go between tabs In the tabbar, the page reloads, the data dosen't stay there from the initial launch of the app

Comment: try setting a boolean flag to false; during render check if flag is not set then get data from url and set flag to true and save the data somewhere; next time when the flag is set it wont load the url data and use the save data.

Comment: something along the lines of https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2 with `FutureBuilder` should work fine in your case.